# Adding ArcGIS JS Direction widget in separate function

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, routing

I am working with ArcGIS JS library, I am trying to add direction widget in my code, and it is working fine. I am following this example:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_directions_basic.html

Now, what I want to do is to add direction widget in separate function and return its object to the calling function, but I am getting undefined when I log returned object. Is ArcGIS JS adding widget asynchronously? If it is then is there any way to add this widget synchronously? I studied the documentation and couldn't find anything related to this. I want to access its object in calling function and I have to initialize this widget in another function. And also, I cannot use global variable for this widget.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Directions Widget</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        body {
            background-color:#FFF;
            overflow:hidden;
            font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/"></script>
    <script>
        function addWidget(map) {
            require([
                "esri/dijit/Directions", "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function(Directions) {
                var directions = new Directions({
                    map: map
                }, "dir");
                directions.startup();
                return directions;
            });
        }
        function init() {
            var map;
            require([
                "esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function(Map) {

                map = new Map("map", {
                    basemap: "streets",
                    center: [-98.56, 39.82],
                    zoom: 4
                });
            });
            var dir = addWidget(map);
            console.log(dir); //undefined
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div id="dir"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```